# temphangle variable missing when using wp_filesystem copy

Tags: filesystem, wp-filesystem, filesystem-api

I get the following error when using `$wp_filesystem->copy();` to copy a file from one destination to another.

```
Undefined variable: temphangle in <b>../htdocs/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-ftpext.php</b> on line <b>159</b>
```

Any idea what **temphangle** is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a typo corrected by SergeyBiryukov in the Github Repo for 5.6 :

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/commit/a5edb2a8a15697440dff359fac53c27dd2067db3